# What's wrong with this XNA 4 Morph target animation

Tags: c#, animation, xna

I found this demo for XNA 3 Morph target animation at Youtube:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6PLtA7wgg0

And here is the download link:

http://mvinetwork.co.uk/permanent/morphtargets/MorphTargetAnimation.zip

This project works fine in XNA 3 (VS2008)

[image]

And then I try to upgrade it to XNA 4 (VS2010)

[image]

I knew there is something wrong, can anyone tell me technically what is wrong?

Any hints, keywords are welcome.

You can find my upgraded project here:

http://code.google.com/p/stack-overflow-questions/downloads/list

Comment: Without knowing much about XNA, I'd probably start by making sure my video drivers where up to date.  While that was happening I'd probably read about breaking changes here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/16/breaking-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: Hi, @ChrisLively you are right, there lots of changes, I follow this  guide 
http://nelxon.com/resources/xna-3-1-to-xna-4-0-cheatsheet.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems like a calculation error of the animation. Morph-Targets have normaly a value between 0f-1f depending on how strong the morph is. When the calculation is wrong it may go up to a higher level. Also it could be a issue when calculate the blending between more than one morph-targets.

Some math code for a simple morph:

> vertexPosition = ((morphVertex - originalVertex) * morphValue) + originalVertex

Now, if you want to morph between different morph targets, a.e. for a speaking character, you have to calculate the `morphValue` for each animation.

If this code is wrong the vertex may end up somewhere where it should not. Imagine the following sample ( One Axis only ):

> morphVertexResult[0] = (((1f   - 0.2f) * 0.6f) + 0.2f) = 0.68f
>   morphVertexResult[1] = (((0.5f - 0.2f) * 0.7f) + 0.2f) = 0.41f
>   vertexPosition = morphVertexResult[0] + morphVertexResult[1] = 1.09f

In this case you get a value of `1.09f` but expect a value which must be between `1f` and `0.2f`. The correct calculation is a little more complex, and the last time i used morph targets i get my morph values from 3Ds Max and they have already been normalized.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the shader on this part.

Comment: But the shader is same for XNA 3 and 4, so it's unlikely the shader is wrong.

Comment: Wait... it's possible... as some functions may not available in XNA 4

Comment: @DuSijun Which functions do you mean? I think the shaders should be downwards compatible.

Comment: Hi, refer to MorphingEffect.fx in the project. The morphing is done by the shader.

Comment: @DuSijun Right the morph is done in the shader, but NOT the calculation of the value which i called `morphValue`. This is the value which must be wrong.

Comment: Got it , I will check it out.